# Url Rewrite Using htaccess not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using this php code in file qas.php

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
include 'head.php';
$qid = $_GET['qid'];
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
$myid = $_SESSION['userid'];
$time = time();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$ans = $_POST['ans'];
mysql_query("insert into qas (aid,qid,uid,answer,time) values ('','$qid','$myid','$ans','$time')");
echo "<div class='menua'>Answer Posted..!!</div><br/>";
}
?>
```

and .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) $ qas.php?qid=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) /$ qas.php?qid=$1
```

but nothing works it says error

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.Please contact the server administrator at admin@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: what do want to archive ?

Comment: And the logs say what? What URL did you try to access? Why are you accessing both $_GET and $_POST in the same code, when those are two separate HTTP methods.

Comment: i m new in php plz elobrate what to do??

Comment: i want something like this http://domain.com/1

Comment: @Zarazthuztra You can access both $_GET and $_POST in PHP - fields posted from a form will only be in $_POST, attributes passed in the URL query string will only be in $_GET.

Comment: @PrinceJuGnU: Can you access your error.log and see what the error is for 500? Is mod_rewrite even enabled?

Comment: yes mod_rewrite enabled

Comment: @Niall That's kind of false bro. GET and POST are HTTP methods. You can set a form to GET if you want, and all the fields are passed via the URL. They're two separate methods, and you can only do one per request.

Comment: @Zarazthuztra The HTTP methods are irrelevant bro. If you have a form like this:

    `<form method="post" action="page.php?param=test">
        <input type="submit" name="button" value="Submit" />
    </form>`

and you click that button, then in page.php you'll have $_GET["param"]=="test" and $_POST["button"]=="Submit". That's just how PHP works, try it if you don't believe me.

Comment: @Niall, that's not really what I'm getting at, and I do apologize for not being more clear. Yes, your above example will work, but not in the reverse, and this is something I dislike about PHP. POST DOES rely on the HTTP method, whereas GET does not. It's in the documentation(http://bit.ly/1dRLqzA) . Switch that form method to get and see what happens. [31-Dec-2013 17:34:49 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: foo in /Users/Work/Web/process.php on line 3
[31-Dec-2013 17:34:49 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: bar in /Users/Work/Web/process.php on line 5.

Comment: @Zarazthuztra I am well aware of that, but it's utterly irrelevant to this question... he's looking up a $_GET value for what he expects to have passed from the rewrite, which is correct, and he's checking for something being POSTed with isset(), which is also correct. In your first comment you told him he couldn't use $_GET and $_POST in the same code, when he can. Now you're just confusing the issue further with something no one was trying to do anyway. It's ok to admit a mistake and let things go sometimes ;)

Comment: @Niall No worries. I often type these in a hurry so I do get a few words mixed up. I accept fault.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space before the $ and /$, so your rules are just like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ qas.php?qid=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ qas.php?qid=$1
```

Also, your PHP is invalid - you've got an opening brace on the first `if` but no closing one. Put a closing } on a new line just after `$time = time();`

Comment: sir php code is working properly i just put a demo of php code it is not full code i pasted here.

Comment: Ok, well you must have missed a brace when copying because the code you pasted has 2 opening { and only 1 closing }. In any case you need to remove those spaces from your RewriteRules for your requests to actually reach your php page.

Comment: yes i removed spaces but still not working. actually i want to make something like this domain.com/username

Comment: I don't know what to tell you Prince, I used your exact code and removing those spaces is all I changed and then it worked. There must be something else wrong about your setup. Can you tell us what your apache error.log says?

Comment: its working now thnx Naill ..and m using both $_GET and $_POST ..everything is working fine now...